# Qual é o objetivo de implementar um método mágico __invoke numa classe?

Tags: php, métodos-mágicos

Eu sei para quê serve o método  `__invoke`. É para que uma classe execute uma ação, caso se chamada como uma função.

Inclusive, a mesma está presente na classe especial do php chamada `Closure`, que é instanciada quando chamamos a *função anônima* no php.

Qual é o objetivo de possuirmos uma classe que pode ser chamada como função, através do método mágico `__invoke`?

```
  class Invokable {

         public function __construct($name)
         {
             $this->name = $name;
         }

         public function __invoke()
         {
              return $this->name;
         }
 }


 $user = new Invokable('Wallace');

 $user(); // "Wallace";
```

Qual é a vantagem/utilidade de se utilizar dessa implementação numa classe de criada pelo usuário? Ou seja, eu estou desconsiderando a já existente implementação da `Closure`.

Comment: Acho que alguém poderia dar uma "incrementada" nas respostas, adicionando detalhes como por exemplo: A instancia da classe que implementa invoke pode ser avaliada como `true` quando usamos `callable` ou `is_callable`.

Comment: Hm, mas isso ja está implícito no trecho da minha resposta que diz que um objeto que implementa __invoke é um callable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`__invoke`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.invoke) faz sentido quando você precisa de um [callable](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.callable.php) que possa manter um estado interno. Digamos que você queira ordernar um array:

```
$arr = [
    ['key' => 3, 'value' => 10, 'weight' => 100], 
    ['key' => 5, 'value' => 10, 'weight' => 50], 
    ['key' => 2, 'value' => 3, 'weight' => 0], 
    ['key' => 4, 'value' => 2, 'weight' => 400], 
    ['key' => 1, 'value' => 9, 'weight' => 150]
];
```

A função [usort](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.usort.php) permite que você ordene um array utilizando uma função, simples. Contudo neste caso queremos ordernar o array com base na chave interna `'value'`, o que pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
$comparisonFn = function($a, $b) {
    return $a['value'] < $b['value'] ? -1 : ($a['value'] > $b['value'] ? 1 : 0);
};
usort($arr, $comparisonFn);

// o resultado vai ser um array onde 
// ['key' => 'w', 'value' => 2] é o primeiro elemento, 
// ['key' => 'w', 'value' => 3] é o segundo, etc
```

Agora talvez você precise reordenar o array, dessa vez com base na chave `key`, seria necessário reescrever a função:

```
usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['key'] < $b['key'] ? -1 : ($a['key'] > $b['key'] ? 1 : 0);
});
```

Como pode ver a lógica da função é idêntica, contudo não pudemos reutilizar a anterior devido a necessidade de ordernar com base em uma chave diferente. Esse problema pode ser resolvido com uma classe que encapsula a lógica de comparação no método `__invoke` e que define a chave a ser utilizada no construtor, ex:

```
class Comparator {
    protected $key;

    public function __construct($key) {
            $this->key = $key;
    }

    public function __invoke($a, $b) {
            return $a[$this->key] < $b[$this->key] ? 
               -1 : ($a[$this->key] > $b[$this->key] ? 1 : 0);
    }
}
```

Um objeto de uma classe que implementa `__invoke` é um "callable", ele pode ser usado em qualquer contexto que uma função poderia, então agora podemos simplesmente instanciar objetos `Comparator` e passá-los como a função de comparação para `usort`:

```
usort($arr, new Comparator('key')); // ordena por 'key'

usort($arr, new Comparator('value')); // ordena por 'value'

usort($arr, new Comparator('weight')); // ordena por 'weight'
```

**Trecho a frente reflete minha opinião, e como tal, subjetiva, você pode parar de ler aqui se quiser ;)**: Embora este seja um exemplo extremamente interessante do uso de `__invoke`, tais casos são raros e eu particularmente ficaria apenas com a compreensão do funcionamento para caso cruze com algum código assim, mas evitaria seu uso já que, embora o exemplo mostrado seja simples, ele pode ser feito de maneiras bem confusas e geralmente existem alternativas mais claras de implementação (embora nem sempre tão abrangentes). Um exemplo no mesmo problema de comparação anterior seria a utilização de uma função que retorne a função comparadora:

```
function getComparisonByKeyFn($key) {
    return function($a, $b) use ($key) {
            return $a[$key] < $b[$key] ? -1 : ($a[$key] > $b[$key] ? 1 : 0);
    };
}
usort($arr, getComparisonByKeyFn('weight'));
usort($arr, getComparisonByKeyFn('key'));
usort($arr, getComparisonByKeyFn('value'));
```

Embora este exemplo exija um pouco de familiaridade com [lambdas | closures | anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.anonymous.php) ele é muito mais conciso já que não cria toda a estrutura de uma classe apenas para armazenar uma simples variável externa.

Comment: Mas particurlamente gostei do exemplo do callable

Comment: Sobre a opinião, eu concordo. Pois é bom evitar obscurecer os códigos. O quanto mais simples e legível, melhor.